# Flutter sqflite open existing database

Tags: database, sqlite, flutter

How can open existing db from assets with flutter and sqflite? 
I read this guide : 
https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/doc/opening_db.md#preloading-data

But my app shows 'not found table' error
Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [Opening an asset database](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/opening_asset_db.md) guide explains the steps you have to do to bundle and open a pre-existing SQLite database inside your Flutter app:.

First, you must edit your `pubspec.yaml` configuration to refer to your pre-existing SQLite database file, so that it gets bundled into your app when the app is built. In this following example, we will assume the file exists at `assets/demo.db` under your Flutter app directory:

```yaml
# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/demo.db
```

Next, in your app initialization, you will need to copy the bundled file data into a usable location, because the bundled resource itself can't be directly opened as a file on Android.

The [`sqflite.getDatabasesPath()`](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/sqflite/latest/sqflite/getDatabasesPath.html) function will return the directory to use for this. This will typically be something like `/data/data/org.example.myapp/databases/` on Android. With this in hand, you can load the byte data from your bundled asset and create the app's writable database file, here named `app.db`:

```dart
// Construct the path to the app's writable database file:
var dbDir = await getDatabasesPath();
var dbPath = join(dbDir, "app.db");

// Delete any existing database:
await deleteDatabase(dbPath);

// Create the writable database file from the bundled demo database file:
ByteData data = await rootBundle.load("assets/demo.db");
List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
await File(dbPath).writeAsBytes(bytes);
```

Finally, you can open the created database file on app startup:

```dart
var db = await openDatabase(dbPath);
```

Comment: @carlfrank Looks like they reorganized. Here's the updated link: https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/opening_asset_db.md