# How to connect SQLite database in Flutter

Tags: database, flutter, sqlite

I have SQLite dababase in my assets folder.
How to connect the existing SQLite database to Flutter and get all items from the table?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter sqflite open existing database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53126885/flutter-sqflite-open-existing-database)

Answer (score 1):

To connect in existing database is :

```
var dbDir = await getDatabasesPath();
var dbPath = join(dbDir, "app.db");


final myDB = await rootBundle.load('assets/myDb.SQLITE');
List<int> bytes = myDB.buffer.asUint8List(myDB.offsetInBytes, myDB.lengthInBytes);
await File(dbPath).writeAsBytes(bytes);

var db = await openDatabase(dbPath);
```

can you read here :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53128435/10649115

And for a complete example you can see this gist:
https://gist.github.com/sergiotucano/57be4db96bfa5d23d68d242d392a9f7d